# Nodejs how to prototype a function to other function ie function.function.function... etc

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to achieve a function or class with unlimited prototypes each of them is function.

for example, there are many modules that provide this kind of functionality.

```
app.url("localhost").port(80).listen
```

or well known eloquents

```
model.where("field","cslkdfja").where("field2","asdfad").count()
```

How can I achieve this kind of approach?

Comment: It's called chaining and you do `function url() {/*...*/ return this;}`

Comment: @Justinas Thanks a lot bro. This is exactly what I was looking for but I did not even know the search query for this problem. You saved my hours..

Comment: This concept is known as [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called function chaining and can be done by returning the enclosing execution context (`this`) from the functions like so:

```js
const obj = {
  func1: function () {
    console.log('func1')
    return this // returning 'this' 
  },

  func2: function () {
    console.log('func2')
    return this // returning 'this'
  },

  func3: function () {
    console.log('func3')
    return this // returning 'this'
  },
}

obj.func1().func2().func3().func1() // Chain all methods
```